# Dropdown Spinner text color

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, styling, textcolor

So I have a spinner that I'm trying to apply a style to. I have a activity theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And a spinner

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/entries"
```

I want the text of the spinner items to appear as white and to do so with xml styling. If I set `android:textColor` in AppTheme, everything works fine.

However this applies to other elements as well.

I have tried the following attribues in AppTheme. None of them have worked.

```
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
<item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>

<style name="SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your AppTheme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/AppTheme.Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/AppTheme.DropDownSpinner</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DropDownSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. Text color stays black. When opening the Spinner I get the following logcat messages:
`W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented`
`W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab48d1a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

I tried searching for these but nothing relevant to Spinners came up.